# Add class to current post title in a list

Tags: php, wordpress

I tried the method in this post.

[Add class to current Wordpress Post Title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50209445/add-class-to-current-wordpress-post-title)

but it doesn't work for me. I have a list of my cpt displayed on a single CPT. I can get the current post ID but not the ID of all the post in the list. So the $loop->ID doesn't return anything.
Here the URL: http://magdakossidas.thomasdesnoyers.com/spectacles/herakles/

Thank you

Comment: Is `$loop->ID` really a thing? Never seen that before. Inside the loop, you should simply be able to use `the_id()` resp. `get_the_id()`, no?

Comment: Yes I did that finaly and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I just get the solution of my own question. I use get_the_ID(); inside the loop to compare with the ID outside the loop.

```
$list_post_id = get_the_ID();
```